# I am creating a website with react.js (tutorial on youtube), but it is failing to compile

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am getting two errors, but I don't know how to solve them

```
Attempted import error: 'styled' is not exported from '../zero-styled' (imported as 'styled').  
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/Badge/Badge.js 36:18-24
export 'styled' (imported as 'styled') was not found in '../zero-styled' (module has no exports)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/Badge/Badge.js 47:19-25
export 'styled' (imported as 'styled') was not found in '../zero-styled' (module has no exports)
```

What does that mean?

i was just following the tutorial and was setting up the folder structure and ran into this problem.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to import `styled` from `../zero-styled`, but `../zero-styled` has no exports at all. Does the file exist?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the version of mui package that was used in the tutorial, because you may be using the latest version which doesn't have any export in the file '../zero-styled'.

Check mui website for the latest importing methods

or try-------

Change the index.js/ main.js file in your react app like :-

```html
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <App />
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: thanks! there was something wrong with the version. I don't know why that happened, because i copied them from his git repository. But now they match to the tutorial and it works.